# Aggregate the latest values from a statistics table into a single row by team_id

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

I've read a [whole](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/230160/how-to-collapse-into-a-single-row-from-multiple-rows) [bunch](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34326/aggregating-statistics-from-child-rows) of StackOverflow [questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/128239/aggregate-data-from-multiple-rows-into-single-row) around this, but I can't seem to crack it so at risk of asking a duplicate question I'm asking my specific one here. I've simplified the question down to a use case without all of the other complexity.

For all of the below, I'm running version 12.9 of postgresql at the time this question is asked.

I have a table of statistics and a table of teams. Teams is simple, just a name and id. The stats table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE stats (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
  team_id integer, 
  calculated_on date, 
  type char(4)
  sample jsonb, 
);
```

The table of statistics is expected to be unique by calculated_on, team_id, and type. The sample is a JSONB with a single value attribute. The two stat types are hits and runs.

The goal is to return the **latest** average stats for each team over the last 7 days, and a comparison of the delta between the latest and last period's stats.

So, if you had:

```
  team_id, calculated_on, type, sample
  1, 2022-01-01, hits, {"value"->2}
  1, 2022-01-02, hits, {"value"->1}
  1, 2022-01-03, hits, {"value"->1}
  1, 2022-01-04, hits, {"value"->1}
  1, 2022-01-05, hits, {"value"->1}
  1, 2022-01-06, hits, {"value"->1}
  1, 2022-01-07, hits, {"value"->1}
  1, 2022-01-08, hits, {"value"->1}
```

Then the resulting rows would look like:

```
team_id, period, avg_hits, avg_runs, avg_hits_delta, avg_runs_delta
1, 2022-01-08, 1, 0, -.5, 0
2, 2022-01-08, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

For Team 1, runs would be 0 because in this example there is no data. For Team 2, everything would be 0 because there is no data. The delta is a comparison to this period's average over last period's average. In this case we only have 1 data point for the previous 7 days so the average is 2.

A few key things..

1. Even if we had months worth of data, we only want the latest period.
2. Ideally the rows are consistent even if the data isn't there. Meaning if we're querying last 7 days but the only data point we have is 8 days ago it will return 0, and it will return a row for each team.
3. This table has millions of rows, so performance is definitely a consideration.

I have [an SQLFiddle that I've put together](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e1109/23) with sample data and a query that.. doesn't work.